# BASH recursive rename of js files to jsx

Tags: files, rename, recursive

On a mac I'm migrating a create react app to vite and have a lot of *.js files that need changing to *.jsx. I done this manually once in my life and this is enough for one eternity.

I need a simple to understand script to do this preferably on a mac installation without needing to install anything.

I'v found lots of existing examples but none I've tried have worked completely.

edit ---

for bonus points, this only happens for files that contain `import React` as this makes the refactor quite quicker with less manual checking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
$ find . -name '*.js' -exec echo mv {} {}x \;
mv ./a/a.js ./a/a.jsx
mv ./a/z/z.js ./a/z/z.jsx
mv ./b/b.js ./b/b.jsx
$
```

Once you're happy with how the proposed commands look, just remove the `echo` part, and give it a spin.

If you have directories named .js, this won't work and will need `-type f` adding.

### Bonus Points Aspect

Per the subsequent edit, to limit the renames just to those files which include a 'import React' line, use the solution below as suggested by @Robert Smith.

```
find . -iname "*.js" -exec grep -q 'import React' {} \; -exec mv "{}" "{}x" \;
```

Comment: fab thanks!!!!!!

Comment: this worked after installing perl rename
find . -name "*.js" -exec rename -v 's/\.js$/\.jsx/i' {} \;**

Comment: any ideas about my edit for **import React** check?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper You don't need `find` if you already have rename installed.

Comment: Reading your edit now, you might need to use find as follows: `find . -iname "*.js" -exec grep -q 'import React' {} \; -exec mv "{}" "{}x" \;`

Comment: I had to alter because all my files do import * as React. So this: `find . -iname "*.js" -exec grep -q 'import \* as React' {} \; -exec mv "{}" "{}x" \;`